# Java Regex: Why is \177 escape code invalid?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using a common regex to validate email. The pattern is this:

```
(^[-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+(\.[-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+)*|^"([\001-\010\013\014\016-\037!#-\[\]-\177]|\\[\001-\011\013\014\016-\177])*")@((?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\.?$)|\[(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\]$
```

Just in case, I DO add all the \ escaping in java, so this is the final pattern that java evaluates. It works in normal online regex evaluators, but when running in Java it throws

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 103

which is the \177 code. Why is that, why is that code illegal and why does it work in online validators?

Comment: What are you trying to represent via `\177`?

Answer (score 5):

[The javadoc of `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) gives the answer for you here; quoting:

```
\0n     The character with octal value 0n (0 <= n <= 7)
\0nn    The character with octal value 0nn (0 <= n <= 7)
\0mnn   The character with octal value 0mnn (0 <= m <= 3, 0 <= n <= 7)
```

The only valid way for an octal escape sequence to appear is the above.

If you write `\1xx`, for whatever `xx`, this will be interpreted as `\1` then `xx`, where `\1` is a back reference to the first capturing group of the regex...

Except that in your case, index 103 is at:

```
...37!#-\[\]-\177]|\\
             ^^ HERE
```

And you are within a character class; and you can't use back references in character classes. The regex engine therefore tries to interpret it as an escape sequence, which is illegal as mentioned above. Hence the message.

Replace that with `\0177` and your problem will be solved.

As a side note, validating emails with regexes, while it is very common, is also a very bad idea. Use javax.mail instead, which can validate mail addresses using [`InternetAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html).

[further note: while the link above is to Java EE, actually you can add javamail as an independent jar to your project; a quick maven search will tell you that]

Comment: The part that scares me about InternetAddress is the javadoc of validate: "The current implementation checks many, but not all, syntax rules."
With this regex, we are at least standardizing the evaluation in multiple platforms, using the same pattern.

Comment: @WilliamMartínezPomares even so, you should be using it and not regexes you find "somewhere". The developers of javamail know their job well enough that the cases when it actually fails to validate what RFC 2822 are close to nil; and surely better than nearly all regexes you'll find out there.

Answer (score 0):

Inline regex validators tend to be misleading, because there are many different flavors of regex. You need a Java regex, but your validator is apparently testing for a related-but-different flavor.

For your specific issue: As you can see from [the documentation for `java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), octal escapes have to start with `\0`, but can have up to three digits after that. So, change `\177` to `\0177`.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of classes Java see's octal as `\0377` to distinguish it from a
backreference.

Other engines will take `\377` form but use an internal capture group
recognition at that point to distinguish it from a backreference.
These other engines won't recognize the `\nnn` form inside classes,
but provide an octal bracket form `\o{nnn}` for that.

As far as I can tell, you can try the `\0377` inside classes and see if
that works, otherwise I don't know if Java recognizes octal's in classes.